# Email alert when private keys read from disk (honeypot, auditd)

Tags: linux, security, https, auditd, alerting

I'd like to receive an immediate alert every time something reads the contents of my private key on Debian Linux. How can I do that?

I have an RSA private key stored on my server's disk at the following location:

```
/etc/ssl/private/super-secret.key
```

It's only readable by root, but I still want to have a log of every time this secret key has been read by a person or a process, and store the context of that read event for alerting and auditing purposes

How can I setup immediate alerting when a very sensitive file has been read from disk?

Comment: Auditing access to files or directories is described in the *"File System"* paragraph of `man 7 audit.rules`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using the following two tools:

1. [auditd](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace) to monitor the file (rather, to tell the kernel to monitor the file's inode) and log all read events to `/var/log/audit/audit.log`
2. [wazuh](https://wazuh.com/) (or ossec) to monitor the `audit.log` file and send an email
   alert when appropriate

### Prereqs

First, install auditd.

```
sudo apt-get install auditd
```

Next, [install wazuh](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/installation-guide/index.html). If you've never done this before and its only one server, you probably want the ["all-in-one" install](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/installation-guide/open-distro/all-in-one-deployment/all_in_one.html).

```
sudo apt-get install wazuh-manager
```

### auditd config

To monitor the file `/etc/ssl/private/super-secret.key`, add an auditd rule to watch (`-w`) the file for read access (`-p r`) -- and give this rule an arbitrary "key" name (`-k audit-wazuh-private-key-r`) so we can match against it later.

```
cat > /etc/audit/rules.d/watch_private_keys.rules <<'EOF'
# monitor reads of our private keys for wazuh
-w /etc/ssl/private/super-secret.key -p r -k audit-wazuh-private-key-r
EOF
```

Restart auditd to apply the rules

```
systemctl restart auditd
auditctl -l
```

### wazuh config

Add the following lines to your wazuh main config file (`/var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf`) to enable monitoring of the auditd log file

```
  <localfile>
    <location>/var/log/audit/audit.log</location>
    <log_format>audit</log_format>
  </localfile>
```

Add the "key" name of our rule above to the list of auditd keys that wazuh monitors

```
grep 'audit-wazuh-private-key-r:read' /var/ossec/etc/lists/audit-keys || echo 'audit-wazuh-private-key-r:read' >> /var/ossec/etc/lists/audit-keys
```

Add the following lines to your wazuh local rules file (`/var/ossec/etc/rules/local_rules.xml`) to tell wazuh that this event is a level 12 = "high important event" and that it should trigger an email alert

```
        <rule id="100002" level="12">
                <if_sid>80700</if_sid>
                <match>audit-wazuh-private-key-r</match>
                <options>alert_by_email</options>
                <description>Audit: Watch - Private Key Read</description>
        </rule>
```

Restart wazuh

```
systemctl restart wazuh
```

Now, any attempt to read the contents of the `/etc/ssl/private/super-secret.key` file will send you an email alert.

### See Also

1. https://wazuh.com/blog/monitoring-root-actions-on-linux-using-auditd-and-wazuh/
2. https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/user-manual/capabilities/system-calls-monitoring/audit-configuration.html